# Why did Anakin & Padme risk having their forbidden marriage witnessed?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

In *Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones (2002)* Anakin and Padme get married. As per the Jedi rules, Jedi are  not allowed to have relationships or marriages.

So why did Anakin & Padme take a huge risk and have someone there at the wedding who knew what they were doing?

[image]

Comment: That's of course the one flaw of that particular movie

Comment: So what's your question? "Why did they allow anyone to be present at their wedding?"

Comment: Then who will perform the marriage?

Comment: why is this question geting Down Vote? what is the reason?

Comment: I suspect its getting downvoted because people think the answer is obvious.  If you want to get married you *have* to have someone perform the ceremony.

Comment: Then it becomes circular .... we have nothing to go on other than the fact that someone married them.  From that it appears that this is normal and/or required in this society.  We have nothing to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Besides, it doesn't matter what you think or I think - this is just my suggestion for why it is getting downvotes.

Comment: I thought I must have been misinterpreting the question, as it seemed so blazingly obvious. Confirming downvote for the circular question. Someone needs to perform the ceremony, in order for a wedding ceremony to be performed.

Comment: **This question isn't nearly as obvious as most are making it to be..** first off, it should be established that SW wedding ceremonies are similar to real-world weddings. Also, I've read somewhere before that Anakin and Padme went by different names when speaking with the priest. Lastly, IMO, the true concern isn't with the priest (since that may bring a degree of confidentiality), but instead, with the droids. It's completely possible that the droids' memory would be reviewed to evaluate events that occurred on Geonosis, which would expose the wedding in the process.

Comment: This question could also be provided a response that addresses Anakin's continuous and increasing friction with the Jedi Order, with Anakin mentioning how Obi-Wan holds him back, and how he's much more skilled than he gets credit for. This progressive kind of disagreement and struggle that Anakin experiences could easily promote him devaluing his membership of the Jedi Order, thus making the seemingly reckless decision to have a traditional wedding ceremony make much more sense. This proposed mentality of Anakin's can be supported by his statements to Padme at the beginning of Episode III.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are breaking **Jedi** rules but no others.

If you want to get married (even in secret) then someone has to make it official or "proper" be it a priest, other religious official or someone with the **legal** authority to do so.

In this case,

> the ceremony was officiated by a Pontifex of the Brotherhood of Cognizance named Maxiron Agolerga who presumably could be relied upon to keep his mouth shut. <sup>*</sup>
>
> <sup>[Source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wedding_of_Anakin_Skywalker_and_Padm%C3%A9_Amidala/Legends)</sup>

<sup>* Probably not the case with C3-PO</sup>

The very fact that they are in a relationship breaches Jedi rules, making it official just makes it harder to undo.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to this is obvious: they needed the man there at the wedding so that he could *actually perform the wedding ceremony*. They could do it all themselves, but it wouldn't have been legally-binding unless done by someone with the correct authority. We don't know how weddings work in the galaxy far, far away, but it's safe to assume they work just as they do here.

In any case, there's no indication that the official knew Anakin was a Jedi. He can't blab to the Jedi Order about Anakin's marriage if he doesn't know Anakin belongs to the Jedi Order.

Comment: so in other universes when they getting Married some on have to allow them by the Low.... :/?

Comment: @RANSARA009 As I said, we don't know for certain, but that does appear to be the case.